# Get ZIP first entry name from remote FTP Server without downloading the zip using Java 8+

Tags: java, zip, ftp-client

I am using FTPClient to download files from my FTP Server , it's full of zip folders that contain from one to many `.txt` files inside . They can be huge in size like ... 10GB .

What i want to do is *without downloading the zip archive from FTP* read the name of the first `.txt` file it has . It's guarranted it will have at least 1 `.txt` file inside it.

I read a very interesting article [here](https://medium.com/@lcjohnny/httpzipstream-extracting-single-entry-from-remote-zip-without-downloading-the-entire-file-7a0f3d24a6fc) but it's in `.NET` and they are using remote URL which is different from my situation .

---

zip format defines some kind of directory pointing to all its inner entries. Containing properties like names, starting offset, size, and other stuff. And that this directory is pretty small, just a few bytes placed on the very end of the archive.

[image]

How i can play around it with FTPCient ?

Comment: I would use something like JSch to establish a SSH connection and execute some shell commands to read the contents of the ZIP file.

Comment: Isn't it overkill ? We have plain FTP . Can't i somehow read some bytes from the zip the tell me which is the first entry.

Comment: As you state yourself that the ZIP directory is placed at the very end of the archive, you can't read it without reading everything else before it. Surely this is obvious?

Comment: @user207421 The is an ftp server which contains  many `.zip folders` each one of the .zip folders contains some .txt files inside . I want to read the first entry let's say from the first .zip folder of the ftp server without downloading it . I posted an answer below on how i managed to do it . Can you let me know if my solution will work for extremely big files ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the following , as far as i see there is not other answer .

---

Example imput (**"ftp-folder/input.txt"**) :

```
public String getZipFirstEntryName(final String remotePath) {                                                                                
    this.log.info("ENTERING getZipFirstEntry, remotePath={} ", remotePath);                                                                  

    /* Setup FTP connection */                                                                                                               
    final FTPClient ftpClient = this.setupFtpConnection();                                                                                   


    try {                                                                                                                                    
        ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory(remotePath.split("/")[0]); /* ftp-folder */                                                                       
    } catch (final IOException e) {                                                                                                          
        e.printStackTrace();                                                                                                                 
    }                                                                                                                                        

    try (final ZipArchiveInputStream zip = new ZipArchiveInputStream(ftpClient.retrieveFileStream(remotePath.split("/")[1]))) { /* input.txt */             

        this.log.info("EXITING getZipFirstEntry, remotePath={} ", remotePath);                                                               
        return zip.getNextEntry().getName();                                                                                                 

    } catch (final IOException e) {                                                                                                          
        e.printStackTrace();               
    }                                                                                                                                        

}
```